# How to set a Custom Theme for Android Projects in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

i have made a custom theme for my android projects with: [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

However, when using Android Studio the program gives out an error.
My project image: [see image](http://uploads.im/a4kKA.jpg)

LogCat Errors:

```
12-18 11:21:59.340    4466-4466/com.example.mohammad.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohammad.myapplication2/com.example.mohammad.myapplication2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.mohammad.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generated the theme from Android Action Bar Style Generator, select the Style compatibility as AppCompat, and regenerate. And i guess you must have left that to the default which was Holo which is creating this error

Regenerating with AppCOmpat Theme should resolve your problem

Comment: tnx you dear #Shiv. This time it runs without error but does not apply. What should I do to apply?

Comment: i sent My codes in Answers 2, please see it and heeeeeelp me :(

Answer (score 0):

my Manifest Code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Tellfaactionbarstyle2">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".cal_activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cal_activity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my style codes :

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu"> 
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item> 
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Tellfaactionbarstyle2" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Tellfaactionbarstyle2.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tellfaactionbarstyle2</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Styles looks good, can you check whether you have any duplicate definitions for the custom theme in your res folder. Also can you check whether you copied all the resource files that were generated out of Android Action Bar Style Generator

Comment: Tnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnx Shiv, its ok and i can use it. thank you dear friend <3

Answer (score 0):

Into you Gradle, insert this line at block Dependencies:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'

Now, you project run successful,

Good luck.